# qt grid layout set content margin not working

Tags: c++, qt

I wanna put a bunch of vertical layouts in a grid layout and the count of those vertical layouts is undefined. in each of those vertical layouts, I have a photo in a label and a title in another label under the photo and I insert this vertical layout into the grid layout:

```
int j = 0;
    ui->profile_post_layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
    for(int i = 0; i < posts.size(); i++)
    {
        QPixmap * pic = new QPixmap(QString::fromStdString(url));
        QPixmap* mypix = new QPixmap(pic->scaled(QSize(50,50),  Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
        QLabel* photo = new QLabel;
        photo->setPixmap(*mypix);
        QLabel* label = new QLabel(QString::fromStdString(title));
        QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;
        layout->addWidget(photo);
        layout->addWidget(label);
        layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
        ui->profile_post_layout->addLayout(layout,j,i);
        if(i % 4 == 0)
            j++;
    }
```

but the result is a photo with a label with too much distance from it meaning the set content margin didn't work. this is the [screenshot](http://s9.postimg.org/7ozm8c3zf/problem.jpg).
how to handle this problem? tnx.

Comment: Is `ui->profile_post_layout` a `QVBoxLayout`?

Comment: @vahancho no, it's a grid layout.

Comment: And where this "sdsad" comes from?

Comment: @vahancho this is the title. I've set label's text to title.        `QLabel* label = new QLabel(QString::fromStdString(title));`

Comment: Hm, but you create as many labels as many images you have in the loop. On the screenshot I see 20 images in the grid, but there is **only one** text label below. How could this happen?

Comment: @vahancho oh, I chose a really bad picture :| sorry. they are all one single picture. not multiple pictures. I chose another photo to prevent ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is too much distance between photos and labels, this is not because assigning `setContentMargins(0,0,0,0)`, in fact by doing so, it makes the distance further (you remove the margins).

One way to make the photo and label compact in the layout, you can try to add the vertical spacer at the end of the loop in the grid layout.

One suggestion in case you have similar problem about layout issue, you can always create a simple test through ui designer and experiment about your actual layout in your coding, this can help to understand the problem.